# Pyinstaller showing console in onedir mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, py2exe

I'm trying to build an exe in --onedir mode because --onefile mode takes a while to start on some computers, but in --onedir mode, when starting the exe a terminal is displayed for a few seconds and then it disappears, but my program works correctly.

Here is the command I used to build the exe:

`pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --windowed --icon "C:/path/to/icon/icon.ico" "C:/path/to/program/main.py"`

I also tried to use a "-w" and "--noconsole" but it didn't work, and I've done some tests and I think the problem is not in my .py program.

My OS: Windows 10 Pro x64, Python 3.6.8 (32 bits), Pyinstaller 4.0

**Solved:** It was (probably) a bug in the getmac library, I replaced with uuid get node and problem solved!

Comment: try to change extension to `.pyw`

Comment: changed and re-built exe but no difference

Comment: please post your code

Comment: thank you I have solved